# Idiomatic way in Emacs Lisp to visit each cons cell in a list?

Tags: emacs, lisp

i would like to visit all the `cons` cells in a list and perform some action on them (including such things as `setcar`).  is there an idiomatic way of doing this?

i can, i think, do something like this

```
(progn
  (setq a (list 1 2 3 4 5 6))
  (setq okay a)
  (while okay
    (if (eq (car okay) 3)
        (setcar okay 22))
    (setq okay (cdr okay))))
```

(where the `if` expression is my "application logic", say.)

but, if there's a terser way of doing this, i'd be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: See the [mapping functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html), in particular `mapcar`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to mutate the cars of the list, then in recent emacsen the likely think you want is `cl-mapl`, which maps a function over successive tails of the list.  This is essentially Common Lisp's `mapl` function: CL has

- `maplist` which maps a function over tails and returns a new list of the values of the function, so `(maplist (lambda (e) e) '(1 2 3))` is `((1 2 3) (2 3) (3))`;
- `mapl` which is like `maplist` but returns the original list.

elisp (courtesy of some now-standard library) now has both `cl-mapl` and `cl-maplist`.

So:

```
> (let ((y (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)))
    (cl-mapl (lambda (tail)
               (rplaca tail 0))
             y)
    y)
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

or

```
> (let ((y (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)))
    (cl-mapl (lambda (tail)
               (rplaca tail (if (cdr tail) (cadr tail) 'fish)))
             y)
    y)
(2 3 4 5 6 7 fish)
```

(In neither of these cases do you need to make sure that `y` is returned: I just did it to make it clear that `y` is being destructively modified by this.)

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(setq a (mapcar (lambda (x) (if (equal x 3) 22 x)) a))
```

That sets the value of variable `a` to the result of changing any members of `a` that are 3 to 22.

Choose the equality operator you want, `equal`, `eql`, or `=`, depending on whether you know that either all list members are numbers (use `=`) or you know that they are either numbers or you want to test object equality otherwise, (use `eql`), or you don't know what they might be (use `equal`).

You haven't indicated any need to do list-structure modification (`setcar`). It appears that all you care about is for `a` to be a list as I described.

Comment: Drew, thanks.  in fact, i do want `setcar`.

Comment: In that case, do what @ignis volens suggested - use `cl-mapl`. (You can use `setcar` or `cl-rplaca` - same thing.)